How do I keep the "Table 1" auto text or how do I reformat "Table Label" style in a linked document
I have a requirement in which the notes section looks like this:
The ARCNET hub external interface shall comprise of the following signals as presented in the Table XX.
With this requirement, I create a linked document that has the table and a table label.
So first thing first, I need to change the style of the caption to be in line with our corporate standard. If I apply our style with the "Update Styles" command, the "Table 1" auto text disappears, but at least the rest of the style is updated correctly.
If, before updating the style, I generate my document, the table labels are there and correctly increments in the document. I can also manually update the style of that "table label" to look correctly and generate and all looks good, but I really do not want to do this for every linked document where I add a table.
QUESTION: How do I keep the "Table 1" auto text or how do I reformat "Table Label" style?
A follow-on question is here: Link to stackoverflow question
I am using EA 16.1 Ultimate on Windows 11.
